# Ionic v5: Link from iFrame does not load on iOS

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, iframe, ionic4, ionic5

I am using an Ionic v5 App on iOS:
I use an iFrame from the external service of the "Deutsche Bahn":
https://www.bahn.de/p/view/home/partnerprogramm/anreiseservice.shtml

```
<iframe src="https://dbaw.specials-bahn.de/149cff8c-5fbd-11ea-8079-00163efd4d20.html" 
        width="100%" 
        height="346" 
        name="iFrame"> 
</iframe>
```

I specified

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

in config.xml, but it is still not possible to open the link of the external iFrame.

Whats the solution for this?

Comment: Try using `allow-intent`

Comment: I added
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
and it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Does the iframe works when serving the ionic application in your browser ? Maybe the target website doesn't allow to be embedded in an iframe

Comment: Yes in the browser it is working… But iOS blocks it…